# Rails Tutorial: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following along with the rails tutorial. I'm on ch. 6 and I'm getting a strange error with SQLite3 (for the record, I'm using sqlite version 1.3.10 and the tutorial uses 1.3.9)

I don't get an error when I run rake db:migrate, but when I run the migration for the test environment, here's what I get:

```
$ bundle exec rake test:models

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError:

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
sample_app/test/models/user_test.rb:1:in `require'
sample_app/test/models/user_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:models
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


$ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

== 20150628011937 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating ===========================
==
    -- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:


SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")sample_app/db/migrate/20150628011937_add_index_to_users_email.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constrain
t failed: users.email: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users"
("email")
sample_app/db/migrate/20150628011937_add_index_to_users_email.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email
sample_app/db/migrate/20150628011937_add_index_to_users_email.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Here is my most recent migration

```
  class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_index :users, :email, unique: true
    end
  end
```

I can post any other files if those are relevant. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Check your `test/fixtures/users.yml` file and make sure `email` is unique for each user.

Comment: The tutorial said to replace all of the contents of that file just the comment "# empty." Should I add anything else?

Comment: That is fine. The tutorial uses `users.yml` only from chapter 8 onwards, and wants it to be empty at this stage. Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to migrate the dev database. `(If this fails, try exiting any running sandbox console sessions, which can lock the database and prevent migrations.)`

Comment: @PrakashMurthy `bundle exec rake db:migrate` doesn't fail & I don't have any running sandbox console sessions

Comment: I had this error in Chapter 8, looks like in the tests that the `fixtures.yml` account name enters in conflict when another `@user.email` is saved. I had to comment out that test

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem was that I had users in the database with the same email before the migration.

`db:reset` solved everything

Comment: Ooooohhhh.. I just got what you meant.  You had users in your database that violated the uniquness rule of the migration, thus the migration wasn't able to go through.  Thanks for posting/ answering.

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't occur to me to check that the data in my column didn't have duplicates. I guess this is why you're supposed to use the sandbox.

Comment: This gives a `Permission denied @ unlink_internal` error

Comment: I had the same problem as this question and your suggestion fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced it for a bit different reason and here is the solution.

For me the error was

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-05-09 18:23:59.827561', '2018-05-09 18:23:59.827561', 298486374)
```

Notice the `INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id")`. It was caused by *test/fixtures/users.yml* was not filled, so then there was duplicate values in columns which has unique key constraint.

*test/fixtures/users.yml*:

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

# This model initially had no columns defined. If you add columns to the
# model remove the '{}' from the fixture names and add the columns immediately
# below each fixture, per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

Comment: I was also missing the fixtures. Your comment helped me look in that direction. Thanks.

Comment: That's beautiful it helped someone. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I fixed it commenting both lines

Comment: I don't think I would consider this a fix. It's more workaround I guess

Answer (score 4):

if you can't `reset:db` you should try to delete it by hand go to db folder and delete the "`development.sqlite3`" and the "`test.sqlite3`" files 
then run 
rails `db:migrate` 
and `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=TEST`

worked for me, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

**If this happens to you when running tests:**

Make sure there are no users fixtures, unless you explicitly define those users with unique attributes.

```
test/fixtures/users.yml
```

When you generate a model, for example:

```
rails g model User
```

Rails automatically creates that file and it looks like:

```
# Read about fixtures at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

# This model initially had no columns defined. If you add columns to the
# model remove the '{}' from the fixture names and add the columns immediately
# below each fixture, per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

This can mess up your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `rake db:test:prepare` and it will copy the dev database to test so you don't need to run the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete *my development.db* to resolve the issue.