# Rails SQL3 uniqueness validation failing

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a site and I have created a migration file to make the name attribute for an item unique. I have added validations to check for uniqueness but all my tests are causing "ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed".

Here are my migration filess

```
class AddIndexToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_index :products, :name, unique: true
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :price
      t.integer :inventory

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my validations

```
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 15}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :price, presence: true, length: {maximum: 15}
  validates :price, presence: true, numericality: {only_float: true, greater_than: 0, less_than: 10000}
  validates :inventory, presence: true, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than: 0, less_than: 10000}
```

Here are my model tests

```
  def setup
    @product = Product.new(name: "Bannana", price: 1.96, inventory: 3)
  end

  test "valid product" do
    assert @product.valid?
  end

  test "products should be unique" do
    duplicate_product = @product.dup
    duplicate_product.name = @product.name.upcase
    @product.save
    assert_not duplicate_product.valid?
  end

  test "check if we can add a product with a negative price or zero" do
    @product.price = -20
    assert_not @product.valid?
    @product.price = 0
    assert_not @product.valid?
  end

  test "check if we can add a product without a name, price, or quantity" do
    @product.name = "     "
    assert_not @product.valid?
    @product.price = nil
    assert_not @product.valid?
    @product.inventory = nil
    assert_not @product.valid?
  end

  test "check if name is too long" do
    @product.name = "This name for a product is way too long for meeeee"
    assert_not @product.valid?
  end
```

Comment: have you check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/31095778/938947, possible can help

Comment: I believe the issue was that my fixtures were being added to the DB before my validations were running